# please help me with solving this ruby sum

Tags: ruby

You have been given 3 integers - N1, N2 and N3. Find how many numbers between N1 and N2 (both inclusive) are divisible by N3. Print these numbers and count. how to find it

Comment: "how to find it" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short [mre] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: Can you show come code? It's unclear where you got stuck. Do you have trouble iterating over the number range, or checking for divisibility, or counting the results? Or maybe you are approaching it in a different way – what is it?

Comment: `n2 = N2/N3` numbers less than or equal to `N2` (excluding zero) are divisible by `N3`. `n1 = (N1-1)/N3` numbers less than  or equal to `N1-1` (excluding zero) are divisible by `N3`. The answer is therefore `n2-n1`. Note that integer division is employed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input

```
N1 = 1
N2 = 100
N3 = 3
```

Let's create the array now

```
a = [*N1..N2]
#=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Code

```
result = a.select { |x| x % 3 == 0 }
```

Or

```
result = a.filter { |x| x.divmod(N3).last.zero? }

p result
p result.count
```

Output

```
#=>[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87, 90, 93, 96, 99]
#=>33
```